# Copy dependencies maven war

Tags: maven-2

When I try to use the plugin "maven-war-plugin", it copies all libraries to / WEB-INF/lib, how to copy to another directory? Example: "/ libtest"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand why you need to do this but I see two points here:

1. Avoiding dependencies to get copied into `WEB-INF/lib` (if not, then just skip the part related to 1.)
2. Getting them copied to another directory.

For 1. I'm assuming you need the dependencies (because you want to compile against them) but if you don't want the Maven War Plugin to copy them in `WEB-INF/lib`, you'll have to play with their `scope`, for example by declaring them as provided.

For 2. the Maven Dependency Plugin will be helpful here and I think you could use [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), for example during the `pre-package` phase. Use it like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>pre-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- configure the plugin here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

And configure the [`outputDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#outputDirectory) (and other parameters you could need).

Comment: 'pre-package' should be 'prepare-package'

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven-dependency-plugin.